# Cannot Import ES6 module into Vue single file component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, es6-modules

I am learning (tinkering with) ES6 modules and Vue.js, single file components (SFC). I built my project with the Vue CLI via the webpack-simple template. I get an error  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" at the line with "settings.mainAlarm.name". "npm run dev" does not throw any errors so I believe the build step is finding (and perhaps ignoring) the settings.js file. What is the best way to import reusable JavaScript into a Vue SFC?

Root.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h4>{{ alarmName }}</h4>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  //const settings =  mainAlarm;
  import settings from './lib/settings.js'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'Welcome to Blah Blah Blah!',
        alarmName: settings.mainAlarm.name
      }
    }
  }
  //console.log(this.alarmName);
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

./lib/settings.js file:

```
export default function () {
    var rtn = {
        mainAlarm: {
            name: "overdueCheckAlarm",
            info: {  delayInMinutes: .01,  periodInMinutes: .25  }
        },
        notificationAudioFile: "ache.mp3",
        baseUrl: "www.xxx.com/xx/xxxx-xxx/"
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: You are exporting a function not an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either your settings file should look like this

```
export default {
  mainAlarm: {
    name: "overdueCheckAlarm",
    info: {  delayInMinutes: .01,  periodInMinutes: .25  }
  },
  notificationAudioFile: "ache.mp3",
  baseUrl: "www.xxx.com/xx/xxxx-xxx/"
}
```

in which case, your component will work as is, or your component should look like this and you can leave the settings file alone

```
<script>
  import settings from './lib/settings.js'

  // settings.js exports a function as the default, so you
  // need to *call* that function
  const localSettings = settings()

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'Welcome to Blah Blah Blah!',
        alarmName: localSettings.mainAlarm.name
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I expect it's the first option you *really* want (I'm not sure why you would want a unique settings object every time you use settings, which is what the code in your question would do).

Comment: Thanks Bert! Tested both options and they do help/work; makes sense as a function is just an object and doesn't do anything unless it's invoked. Next step would be parameterize the settings using component props...I guess. I'm trying to learn ES6 fundamentals along side SFC...so I would like to incorporate say default parm's and perhaps get my head around destructuring...at risk of my head exploding! Thanks ALL